# Why is this not working? Java

Tags: java, string, if-statement, irc

```
public void onMessage(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname, String message) {
    if (message.toLowerCase().startsWith("!up")) {
        String[] args = message.split(" ");
        String pass = "password";
        if (args[1] == pass){
            op(channel, sender);
            sendMessage(channel, sender+": you now have op");
        }else{
            sendMessage(channel, sender+ " incorrect pass");
            sendMessage(channel, "" +args[1]);
        }
        }
    }
```

this is supposed to check if the user enters `!up password`
no matter what i do, it always says password incorrect. what did I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java String.equals versus ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use String#equals instead of `==` to compare strings.

So instead of:

```
if (args[1] == pass) {
   ...
}
```

You should use:

```
if (args[1].equals(pass)) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
args[1].equals(pass)
```

instead of `args[1]==pass`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (args[1] == pass)
```

should be changed to

```
if(args[1].equals(pass)
```

because in == case compiler checks the reference values which are different, but when equals() is used instead of reference the content of the strings are checked.

Answer (score 0):

You must use if (args[1].equals(pass))